# restoring database to mariadb on raspberry pi very slow

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi, mariadb, database-restore

I have a sql dump with extension .dmp

I am restoring it in mariadb installed on a raspberry pi 3. The database has 9Gb of size and the SD is 32 and have nothing more than the OS (raspbian) installed in it.

The problem is that this restore operation is taking very long. I believe some kind of error is appearing during the process (i can see the row being inserted in a IDE but after a few thousands, it stops or becomes very slow) but i dont know how to debug it.

How can i sucessfuly restore the DB?

Thank you very much,

Comment: MariaDB config was tuned? There is patern to be less secure but more performant. SD card is slow during many small writes

Comment: mariadb config is not tuned. It is as it came....